# How to use temporal validity in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

How to design a table in Oracle 11g so that it is compatible later on with the new *"Temporal validity"* feature in Oracle 12c?

The online documentation of Oracle 12c specifies how to define temporal validity inthe SQL Language guide (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#CJADHJHB)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (PERIOD FOR my_valid_time (my_valid_start, my_valid_end) );
```

So one could use the good old valid_from and valid_till columns already in 11g and beef them up to proper periods in 12c, right?

I've inherited databases that use fixed magic dates for "since always" and "for ever", for instance `DATE '1900-01-01'` and `DATE '3999-12-31'`. Apparently, 12c uses `NULL` instead.

So, do we have to abandon using fixed magic dates and switch to `NULL` dates?

Comment: Great question on 12c! I haven't yet used 12c yet so just adding a comment instead of an answer. My initial reading on the Temporarl Validity feature is that, while NULLs would be preferable, the magic dates would also work just as well. They might interfer somewhat with Oracle's CBO and cause poor query plans, but that's always been the case with magic values anyway; and 12c's new histograms might go some way to mitigating this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to ALTER the table in 12c to enable Temporal Validity (see the ALTER TABLE section of the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_3001.htm#CJAEGCFI)

It works by converting your where clause to a "<=" and "> or is null" clause, so you don't need to change the fixed dates if you don't want to.

Tom Kyte just posted on his blog about this today, with some execellent examples:
http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2013/07/12c-flashforward-flashback-or-see-it-as.html

Comment: +1 for the Tom Kyte link, truly excellently explained. And you're right of course, `NULL` _and_ `1900` will both work, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is there a way to define constraints on these periods to prevent overlapping ranges?