# run before trigger only once to insert multiple rows PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a few parameterization tables, where i need to add history version via two columns VALID_FROM and VALID_TO. Before inserting rows i have two precondition:

1) every record, which is in table get new value in column VALID_TO (sysday - 1) 
2) if exists some records in a table which have same  date as sysdate (DD.MM.YYYY), they must be deleted.

table before inserting rows

```
columnA VALID_FROM  VALID_TO
row1    1.1.2016    31.12.2999
row2    1.1.2016    31.12.2999
row3    3.1.2016    31.12.2999
```

table after inserting rows

```
columnA VALID_FROM  VALID_TO
row1    1.1.2016    24.6.2018
row2    1.1.2016    24.6.2018
row3    3.1.2016    24.6.2018
row1    25.6.2018   31.12.2999
row2    25.6.2018   31.12.2999
row3    25.6.2018   31.12.2999
row4    25.6.2018   31.12.2999
```

These two steps should be finished before inserting new rows and should be automatic. This is the assignment of the task I received. I cant change it.

I tried to create before insert trigger with global temporary table to avoid ora mutating error, but its not working, because every inserted row is deleted and dates in columns VALID_FROM and VALID to are not correct too. So I need to check old records in table only once and then insert all rows without checking

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_DATE_PARM_TABLE_MUT2
 after INSERT on TMP_GR_PARM_IDP_IC_CUST
 FOR each ROW
 BEGIN
   --if exists record which have todas date, then delete
  delete from GR_PARM_IDP_IC_CUST1 where DT_VALID_FROM = get_sysdate;
  --change date in VALID_TO for old records
  update GR_PARM_IDP_IC_CUST1 a set
  DT_VALID_TO = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  where DT_VALID_TO = '31.12.2999';
 --insert records from temporary table into normal parametrization table
  insert into GR_PARM_IDP_IC_CUST1 values (:new.RELATION, :new.DT_VALID_FROM, :new.DT_VALID_TO);
END;
```

Its is possible solve this problem with trigger? If yes, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible via TRIGGER.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, just execute it `BEFORE INSERT` instead of `AFTER INSERT`. And I don't see why you need a global temporary table. Does the following trigger fulfill your requirements?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ti_mytable 
  BEFORE INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM mytable WHERE valid_from = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  UPDATE mytable SET valid_to = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
  :new.valid_from := TRUNC(SYSDATE);
  :new.valid_to := DATE '2999-12-31';
END ti_mytable;
/

SELECT * FROM mytable;
COLA  VALID_FROM   VALID_TO
1     01.01.2016   31.12.2999
2     01.01.2016   31.12.2999
3     03.01.2016   31.12.2999

INSERT INTO mytable (cola) VALUES (4);
1 row inserted.
SELECT * FROM mytable;
COLA  VALID_FROM   VALID_TO
1     01.01.2016   24.06.2018
2     01.01.2016   24.06.2018
3     03.01.2016   24.06.2018
4     25.06.2018   31.12.2999
```

Furthermore, I'd recommend to store dates always as datatype `DATE` and never as a string / datatype `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: i use temporary table, because i get ORA-04091: table is mutating. Try to run code below

`insert all
into  mytable values (4, '01.01.2018', '31.12.2999')
into  mytable values (5, '01.01.2018', '31.12.2999')
select * from dual;`

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question, and why you said "multiple rows" in the question title.

Comment: No, sorry, can't do it. The trigger needs to fire on `INSERT`, but is inserting rows itself, causing a recursion.

Comment: thx for response, i have same opinion, but I wanted to try if someone would come up with a smarter solution.

Comment: Thanks to your question, I've looked into compound triggers, which will get you quite a long way. The traditional solution is of course a separate history table with the old values. The fancy solution is probably [temporal validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344158/how-to-use-temporal-validity-in-oracle-12c).